# making tabs with validation in registration form magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, forms, jquery, validation

i have vendor registration from but it is so simple!
i want to add some tabs labeling "step1 , step2 , step3" which go to next tab only if the vendor have filled the required feild of first tab.
here is the code of registration from

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session =$objectManager-
>create('Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManager');

if($session->getVendorData())
{
  $vendorsession = $session->getVendorData();
}else
  {
$vendorsession = null;
 }

 $countryObject = $objectManager-
   >create('Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country'); 
  $countries = $countryObject->toOptionArray();
   $priceObject = $objectManager-
   >create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data');

  $proofCollection = $block->getProofTypes();


$dir_name = 'vendor/varifications';
$this->helper('\Medma\MarketPlace\Helper\Data')->getImagesDir($dir_name);

$total_file_upload = 0;

?>

 <div style='width:100%;float:left;margin-bottom:15px;'>
<form class="form create account form-create-account" 
   enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $block-
 >getPostActionUrl() ?>" data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}' method="post" 
  style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;content-align:center;">
<fieldset class="fieldset create info">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Personal Information'); ?></span></legend><br>


    <div class="field firstname required">
        <label class="label" for="firstname"><span><?php echo __('First Name'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" onKeyDown="validate(this.id,'<?php echo __('First name'); ?>',15)" maxlength="15" value="<?php if($vendorsession['firstname']){ echo $vendorsession['firstname'];}?>" title="<?php echo __('First Name'); ?>" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}"  aria-required="true">
            <div class="note" id="firstnamepromptmsg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field lastname required">
        <label class="label" for="lastname"><span><?php echo __('Last Name'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" onKeyDown="validate(this.id,'<?php echo __('Last name'); ?>',15)"  maxlength="15" value="<?php if($vendorsession['lastname']){ echo $vendorsession['lastname'];}?>" title="<?php echo __('Last Name'); ?></" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
            <div class="note" id="lastnamepromptmsg"></div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field required">
        <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Email Address'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email_address"value="<?php if($vendorsession['email']){ echo $vendorsession['email'];}?>" title="<?php echo __('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" aria-required="true">
        </div>
    </div>

    <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Business Information'); ?></span></legend><br>

    <div class="field field-name-lastname required">
        <label class="label" for="shop_name"><span><?php echo __('Shop Name'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="shop_name" name="shop_name"  onKeyDown="validate(this.id,'<?php echo __('Shop name'); ?>',20)" maxlength="20" value="<?php if($vendorsession['shop_name']){ echo $vendorsession['shop_name'];}?>" title="<?php echo __('Shop Name'); ?></" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
            <div class="note" id="shop_namepromptmsg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="field required">
        <label for="country" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Country'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="country" id="country" title="<?php echo __('Country'); ?>"  class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true"> 
                <?php foreach($countries as $value=>$key):?>
                        <option <?php if($vendorsession['country']==$key['value']):?>selected='selected'<?php endif;?> value="<?php echo $key['value'];?>"><?php echo $key['label']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field field-name-lastname required">
        <label class="label" for="shop_address"><span><?php echo __('Shop address'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" id="shop_address" name="shop_address"  onKeyDown="validate(this.id,'<?php echo __('Shop address'); ?>',20)" maxlength="200" value="<?php if($vendorsession['shop_address']){ echo $vendorsession['shop_address'];}?>" title="<?php echo __('Shop address'); ?></" class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
            <div class="note" id="shop_addresspromptmsg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field field-name-lastname required">
        <label class="label" for="contact_number"><span><?php echo __('Contact Number'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input id="contact_number" name="contact_number" value="<?php if($vendorsession['contact_number']){ echo $vendorsession['contact_number'];}?>" onKeyDown="validatenumber(this.id,'<?php echo __('Contact number') ?>',12)"  maxlength="12" title="<?php echo __('Contact Number'); ?></" class="required-entry" type="number" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
                <div class="note" id="contactnumpromptmsg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <?php if($proofCollection->getSize()>0){ 
            $total_file_upload = 1; ?>
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Verification Proof'); ?></span></legend><br>

    <div class="field required">
        <label for="proof_type" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Proof Type'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <select name="proof_type" id="proof_type" title="<?php echo __('Proof Type'); ?>">
                <option value="">-<?php echo __('Select'); ?>-</option>
                <?php foreach($proofCollection->getData() as $proofData):?>
                        <option <?php if($vendorsession['proof_type']==$proofData['entity_id']):?>selected='selected'<?php endif;?>   value="<?php echo $proofData['entity_id'];?>"><?php echo $proofData['name']; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field field-name-lastname required">
        <label class="label" for="contact_number"><span><?php echo __('Files'); ?></span></label><span class="note"><?php echo __('( supported format PNG, JPEG, JPG, BMP)');?></span>
        <div id="verification_proof_container" style="padding-left:160px;">
            <div class="control">
                <input  title="<?php echo __('Files'); ?>" type="file" name="varification_proof_1" id="varification_proof_1"  class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="field field-name-lastname required">
        <div class="control" style="padding-left:160px;">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo __('Add New') ?>" class="action submit primary" onclick="addNewFileUpload()">
                <span><span><?php echo __('Add New'); ?></span></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="total_file_upload" id="total_file_upload" value="<?php echo $total_file_upload;?>">

    <legend class="legend"><span><?php echo __('Login Information'); ?></span></legend><br>

    <div class="field required">
        <label for="username" class="label"><span><?php echo __('User Name'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="username" value="<?php if($vendorsession['username']){ echo $vendorsession['username'];}?>" id="username" type="text" class="input-text" title="<?php echo __('User Name') ?>" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true"> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field required">
        <label for="password" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Password'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="<?php echo __('Password') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true">
               <div class="note" id="passwordmsg"><?php echo __('( Your password must include both numeric and alphabetic characters)');?></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field required">
        <label for="confirmation" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Confirm Password'); ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="password" name="confirmation" onblur="validatepassword()" id="confirmation"  title="<?php echo __('Confirm Password') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true"> 
            <div class="note" id="passwordmsg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>





  </fieldset>


<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" title="Save"><span><?php echo __('Save'); ?></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>"><span><?php echo __('Back'); ?></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
  </form>
        <div class="seller-login-div">
                <div class="login-content">
                         <h2 class="heading">Already Registered  as seller?</h2>
           <?php ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $this-
           >helper('\Medma\MarketPlace\Helper\Data')->getSellerUrl();?>">
        <button type="submit" class="action primary seller-login-button">Log 
       In as Seller</button>
    </form>
</div

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addNewFileUpload()
    {
        var total_file_upload = jQuery('#total_file_upload').val();
        total_file_upload = parseInt(total_file_upload)+1;

        var content = '<br><div class="control"><input  title="<?php echo __('Files'); ?>" type="file" name="varification_proof_'+total_file_upload+'" id="varification_proof_'+total_file_upload+'"  class="input-text required-entry" data-validate="{required:true}" aria-required="true" /></div>';

        jQuery('#verification_proof_container').append(content);

        jQuery('#total_file_upload').val(total_file_upload);
    }
    function validate(id,field,limit)
    {
        console.log('#'+id);
        value = jQuery('#'+id).val();
        console.log(value.length+'======='+limit);
        if(value.length==limit)
        {
        jQuery('#'+id+'promptmsg').html(field+' must contain '+limit+' characters');
        jQuery('div #'+id+'promptmsg').css('display','block');
        }
        else
        {
            jQuery('div #'+id+'promptmsg').css('display','none');
        }
    }
    function validatenumber(id,field,limit)
    {
        console.log('#'+id);
        var value = jQuery('#'+id).val();
        if (value.length>=limit) {
            console.log(value.length+'======='+limit);
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').html('Invalid contact number');
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').css('display','block');
        } else {
            jQuery('#contactnumpromptmsg').css('display','none');
        }
    }
    function validatepassword()
    {
         var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
         var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confirmation").value;
         if (password != confirmPassword) 
         {
            jQuery('#passwordmsg').html('Passwords do not match.');
            jQuery('#passwordmsg').css('display','block');
         }
         else
         {
             jQuery('#passwordmsg').css('display','none');
         }

    }

</script>
```

destroy();?>

i don't have any knowledge about juery any help regarding creating tabs with validation may help me.

Answer (score 0):

ever heard of modal? Try something like this:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html

```
<div id="model_content_1">Content goes here</div>

$('#modal_content').modal({
    <option1>: <value1>,
    <option2>: <value2>,
    ...
});
```

Comment: can you simple guide me to a function by which i can create tab and make it move to next step only if the first step has been filled?

Comment: @Laiba I think you can search for key word modal in .phtml files in any m2 project and look for example. Also I dont think there is a m2 function that helps you with that b/c modal is js, not php